# How do I restrict my custom control's children to a certain area?

Tags: delphi

I have a custom control based on `TPanel`, and it has an inner panel that defines the working region for my components and a outer area with a "minimize/restore" button to hide and show the (inner) panel.

If I drop a component at design time on my control and set its `Align` property to `alClient`, the size of the outer panel is used and the minimize button is no longer visible.

How can I align or drop components on my panel to force them (to stay) within the area of the inner panel?

[image: screen shot showing region of inner frame, where children belong]

Comment: if only needed for  alclient, just set paddings of your Hidepanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the button on an own panel which will not accept other controls and keep it in front, but would have the disadvantage that other controls could be covered.

```
procedure THidePanel.AdjustClientRect(var Rect: TRect);
begin
  inherited;
  FPanel.BringToFront;
end;

constructor THidePanel.create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FPanel := TPanel.Create(self);
  FPanel.Align := alright;
  FPanel.Parent := self;
  FPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  FPanel.Width := 30;
  FButton:=TSpeedButton.Create(self);
  FButton.Parent := FPanel;
  FPanel.ControlStyle := FPanel.ControlStyle - [csAcceptsControls];
end;
```